Type error with React Navigation's CompositeScreenProps for Nested Navigators
I'm trying to follow this guide for type checking with TypeScript and React Navigation but I'm getting this error anytime I try to navigate to a screen in another tab:
Argument of type '[AppRoutes.LIBRARY_TAB, { screen: AppRoutes; params: { title: string; }; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[screen: AppRoutes.LIBRARY_TAB] | [screen: AppRoutes.LIBRARY_TAB, params: LibraryStackParamList]'.
  Type '[AppRoutes.LIBRARY_TAB, { screen: AppRoutes; params: { title: string; }; }]' is not assignable to type '[screen: AppRoutes.LIBRARY_TAB, params: LibraryStackParamList]'.
    Type at position 1 in source is not compatible with type at position 1 in target.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'screen' does not exist in type 'LibraryStackParamList'.ts(2345)

Here are my component props:
type ConversationScreenProps = CompositeScreenProps<
    StackScreenProps<HomeStackParamList, AppRoutes.CONVERSATION>,
    BottomTabScreenProps<MainTabsParamList, AppRoutes.HOME_TAB>
>;

And I'm navigating to the screen like this:
navigation.navigate(AppRoutes.LIBRARY_TAB, {
    screen: AppRoutes.MEDITATION_PLAYER, // This is where the error shows up
    params: {
        title: suggestedMeditation,
    },
});

My stack/tabs nesting structure is like this:
- MainStack (NativeStackNavigator)
  - MainTabs (BottomTabNavigator)
    - HomeStack (StackNavigator)
      - ConversationScreen
      - ...
    - LibraryStack (StackNavigator)
      - LibraryHomeScreen
      - MeditationPlayerScreen
      - ...
  - ...

Here are some of the types for my tabs and stacks:
export type MainStackParamList = {
    [AppRoutes.MAIN_TABS]: undefined;
    ...
};

export type MainTabsParamList = {
    [AppRoutes.HOME_TAB]: HomeStackParamList;
    [AppRoutes.LIBRARY_TAB]: LibraryStackParamList;
    ...
};

export type LibraryStackParamList = {
    [AppRoutes.LIBRARY_HOME]: undefined;
    [AppRoutes.MEDITATION_PLAYER]: {
        title: string;
    };
    ...
};

export type ConversationScreenParamList = {
    conversationId?: string;
};

export type HomeStackParamList = {
    [AppRoutes.HOME_SCREEN]: undefined;
    [AppRoutes.CONVERSATION]: ConversationScreenParamList | undefined;
    ...
};


I'm pretty sure I need to use the composite navigator (since I'm navigating across tabs/stacks), but it seems like I'm doing it wrong? Any idea what I need to change so it's not throwing a type error?
Let me know if I should include any other specific info or code (e.g. where I'm declaring my stacks/tabs).

From the documentation about type checking on nested navigators:

To be able to type check this, we need to extract the params from the screen containing the nested navigator. This can be done using the NavigatorScreenParams utility

So you need to change this:
export type MainTabsParamList = {
    [AppRoutes.HOME_TAB]: HomeStackParamList;
    [AppRoutes.LIBRARY_TAB]: LibraryStackParamList;
    ...
};

To this:
export type MainTabsParamList = {
    [AppRoutes.HOME_TAB]: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeStackParamList>;
    [AppRoutes.LIBRARY_TAB]: <LibraryStackParamList>;
    ...
};

